# Color Rows based on repeated dates - Excel VBA

Tags: excel

I have 2 excel sheets that need reconciling every month.  One from a non-profit's membership software and one from Stripe payments.
I have figured out how to use VLOOKUP to combine the needed data but it would make life easy if I could color the multiple rows that have the same deposit batch date.
I have manually done it (too) many times - What I do now is I highlight the multiple lines that have the same batch date and color them.  I alternate with ROY G BIV (Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Indigo, and Violet).
It makes reconciling the transactions and deposits possible.
It has been 40 years since I took BASIC in High school but I think some sort of If statement with an array of the colors (along with proper formatting!) could work?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS  For the grouped rows I would also like to sum a column of payments and apply the total to a cell within the color band (last row of the grouping)

Comment: You could use conditional formatting.
Do a search for "conditional format dates" and you will learn.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I had thought of that but I do not see a way to do a grouping.  It would need to compare to the row above and either use same color or the next color depending on if it were the same batch date.  Then how would I set a color list to use and restart the list when it reached the end?  In my foggy memory I could see using a set of nested loops and advancing the color each time it didn't match and using an array list of colors but that is probably not even the right terminology for anything anymore...

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/custom-conditional-formatting-rules-for-dates-3123335